Control multiple push buttons on a raspberry pi using an mcp23017 over C++
Having followed various tutorials on the web (i.e. 1,2), I have made the following connections:

To enhance clarity, I post another picture depicting the connections on the mpc23017 using a cropped frame from the official datasheet.

Even though wiringPi has been abandoned by the author, I am using this wiringPi - which is fairly maintained by the community. My code is as follows:
#include <iostream>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <mcp23017.h>

int main (){

        wiringPiSetupGpio();
        mcp23017Setup(100, 0x20); //$ sudo i2cdetect -y 1 gives the address 20.

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i){
                pinMode(100 + i, INPUT);
        }

        while( true ){
                for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i){
                        int sig = digitalRead(100 + i);
                        std::cout<<sig<<" ";
                }std::cout<<std::endl;

                delay(500);
        }
        return 0;
}

... but I am getting irrelevant output.
...
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
...

Therefore, if I may ask,

Do you think the connections are correct? (Especially those on the A0,A1,A2,RESET pins)
Or do you think the error lies on the code?
Other than that, what could be possibly wrong?

image links:
img1
img1
img2

Edit: Despite not affecting the issue described in the post, I realized I miss-drew the SDA & SCL connections on the diagrams, misinterpreting the primary wiring. The connections seen in the corrected image (image 1) depict the actual wiring (SDA->GPIO 2, SCL->GPIO 3), but I found it helpful to replace the image for anyone who visits the post afterward

What connections?  A diagram showing what you intend does not show what you did. Why not get one button working before trying multiple buttons?

I don t understand what you mean. The first image on the post shows all the connections

It does not show any connections.  It shows what you planned to connect.  We need to know what you actually connected. i.e. clear photos of your kit showing the wiring.

So you mean this thing https://postimg.cc/XGSM4pfR. I hope you can understand now my motivation on drawing the connections instead :)

Yes... I understand your motivation for the nice, neat wiring diagrams, but that doesn't change the fact that the actual wiring/interconnection is a bit unruly! But first, let's address an issue in your comments: When replying to a comment, you should address your comment to the appropriate party; e.g. @joan : .... This addressing is unnecessary when posting a comment to a Q or A as it always is addressed to the author of the Q or A.

Troubleshooting something like this must proceed in an organized, methodical fashion if it is to be successful. Perhaps you've done this already... But as you did not mention it in your Q, I have to ask in this comment to learn whether you did it or not: 'Did you declare your I2C connection in your config.txt file??'  AND  'Did you verify the I2C connection using i2cdetect??`

@Seamus hello there. I kindly thank you for your input. You are right. I have already activate the i2c , and to make you informed of that I preferred posting it within the code as comment instead of explicitly declaring it. You may check the line in code where I comment this --> //$ sudo i2cdetect -y 1 gives the address 20. . But you are right, next time I ll have this in mind

That's not what I asked... please read my comment again, and ponder the questions in that comment.

Ok I see. Well, here we go. As for verifying the I2c connection, I did. As for the config.txt I assume you mean the manual enabling of the I2c which I did using the dietpi-config. If that's not the case please elaborate further

Hey @Seamus. Take a look at that https://postimg.cc/Xp7b7tHs Better isn't?? :)

"... enabling of the I2c which I did using the dietpi-config." Mmm... my advice is to refrain from calling it dietpi-config. That is an inaccurate and confusing term; consider using config.txt, most people will understand what you mean. And, "Yes - that's an improvement in your wiring!"  :)

@Seamus: Ok great I ll have that in mind. Thnx

The problem is fixed by activating the internal pull-up resistors of the MCP23017 (refer to page 22 of the datasheet).
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i){
    pinMode(100 + i, INPUT);
    pullUpDnControl (100 + i, PUD_UP) ; // <-- activate the pull-up resistors
}

If one uses a different chip, please make sure to connect a resistor to each switch to tie the input to the ground instead.

Good work!  Be sure to select your answer as the correct one when you can. That will let others know this is a valid solution!

Sure. I have to wait for some hours but as soon as the platform allows me, I ll mark the answer as the correct one
